# data is not shown in proper order

Tags: php, html, mysql

Below is my php code I want to show data in html table by reverse order of date
but it is not working where is mistake I do not find
My select query is as follows

```
Select a.wono,date_format(b.wodt,'%Y/%m/%d') as mydate from wodtl_box a, wohdr_box b where a.wono=b.wono order by date_format(b.wodt,'%Y/%m/%d') DESC
```

Comment: Please include all your relevant code and use the code format. No one will be able to read this.

Comment: What is your exact problem? What is the order you want it, what does it give? Any errors?

Comment: Today  24/02/2016 first, then 23/02/2016 second, 22/02/2016 third and so on ....... 01/02/2016

Comment: So I asume you get data from that query but is ordered in an undesired way?

Comment: yes I retrieves data by query and query works perfectly in phpmyadmin in sql but not in php html form

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so you are ordering by `DESC`. That means it starts at the last, so that's where your mistake is. Remove the `DESC` from the end of your query and you should be good to go. (ORDER BY automatically uses `ASC` if `DESC` is not added).

Your query would be:

```
Select a.wono,date_format(b.wodt,'%Y/%m/%d') as mydate from wodtl_box a, wohdr_box b where a.wono=b.wono order by date_format(b.wodt,'%Y/%m/%d')
```

For some more information: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp

Comment: no still it is not working I removed DESC word from query

Comment: query is working fine in phpmyadmin but in dataTable it is not working

Comment: That is very weird.. might showing us a screenshot of the result and the wanted result? As well as a screenshot of the query in phpMyAdmin?

Comment: Screen shot is as follows